# Creating a static IP

Tags: configuration, ip

What I want to do is create a static IP for my Ubuntu Server 16.04. I understand how to do it in general but I don't understand the background.

So I have one external IP from my ISP and it gets changed to local IP addresses through my router. Therefore, two connections, one hardwired and one wireless but they both have different IP addresses so how is it possible to make one static?

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe it is like this: As an example. From my router, I see my ip is 10.12.0.1 -- my ethernet is 10.12.0.111 -- my wireless is 10.12.0.112 ----- so does that mean to create a static IP I use 10.12.0.1?

Comment: From what you have written I'm not sure if you understand it in general. Could you explain in simple English what you want to achieve? Like "*I want to connect with ... from ... to ... because ...*"

Comment: My apologies, I mean I am trying to make a webserver on Ubuntu Server for an intranet.  I have installed a CMS already and it works fine. Then I did this: $CFG->wwwroot change to http://ip.address.of.server instead of http://ip.address.of.server/apples and the IP is changes so that is why I am trying to change to static -- unless I am talking out of my rear end and I don't know what I am doing!??

Comment: I gave you a template for the explanation, right? You ignored it, right?

Comment: Ooops sorry, wasn't ignoring, just didn't realize that was what you wanted. --- I want to connect with home server --- from other  computers on same LAN --- to webserver ---- because $CFG->wwwroot change to ip.address.of.server instead of ip.address.of.server/apples and the IP changes.

Comment: I suspect that the easiest option is to still use DHCP for the router but set the router to give a  specified address to your device when requested. Easier than setting strictly static settings and most modern routers will do this.  Which router are you using?

Comment: TP Link Archer C7. Thanks Andrew I take a look.

Comment: I still have no clue what you are asking about. Example response to what I asked for: "I want to connect **with** Firefox **from** a Windows 10 machine at 10.12.0.120 **to** a working webserver at 10.12.0.121" (no "because" in this case because it is so straightforward it is unnecessary). Your problem seems to have nothing to do with static IP, actually there seems to be no network problem at all. It seems like you don't have a working webserver because you misconfigured it or focus on some tutorial that suggests binding to a determined IP address.

Comment: If so, just put `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces. And edit your question with a clear message in simple language. Not what you "think it's like", not what you think you should do now, but what you did so fat and what you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: Sorry techraf. My fault. I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a static IP.  You order one from a provider.  An ISP will charge more for a static IP than for a dynamic IP.

If you want to have a public server you would order a static IP for your server... one that doesn't change.

If you have other computers and devices on your network, you might consider ordering two IPs.  One for your server and the for your other devices that will go through a router... sharing the one IP.

If you want to have a public server it would need to be associated with an IP that doesn't change (static).  Otherwise it will stop working every time the IP changes and may take sometimes 3 days for the new IP to be propagated throughout.